# Parameter is not valid exception in c#

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I wrote following code to pass picture from the data base to picure box in c#. I got this code from the microsoft .here's the url of that page.[Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317701)

When I run this code it's display parameter is not valid exception.

Whats wrong with this code?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String strCn =@"Data Source=DESKTOP-ROF2H0M\BHAGI;Initial Catalog=Golden;Integrated Security=True";

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strCn);
        cn.Open();


        //Retrieve BLOB from database into DataSet.
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT User_id ,img FROM login", cn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "login");
        int c = ds.Tables["login"].Rows.Count;


        if (c > 0)
        {   //BLOB is read into Byte array, then used to construct MemoryStream,
            //then passed to PictureBox.
            Byte[] byteBLOBData = new Byte[0];
            byteBLOBData = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["login"].Rows[c-1]["img"]);
            MemoryStream stmBLOBData = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData);
        }
        cn.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I got the following error message.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

Here is the snap of my database.
[LOgin Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9L8H.png)

Comment: Could you share more information about `display parameter is not valid exception`

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Heres the erorr message I got=> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

Comment: This error message is usually given when the image supplied to the `PictureBox` is invalid. Save your byte array to a file first (as a debugging step) to confirm that the image is valid; It will probably not be.

Comment: What is the format of the data of the binary blob? How is that generated?

Comment: You are in bad way, You'r sql connection is not handled in right way

Comment: @ImranShams can u Plese show me the way to connect database?

Comment: Do you read my last answer edit? You need some changes in DB and Code of your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 problem (Performance & Security issue):

1. You need to handle SQL connection
2. You need to store files (Binary & Images) on disk (No Database)
3. Never try to store users password without encryption (Like MD5)

---

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    string strCn = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-ROF2H0M\BHAGI;Initial Catalog=Golden;Integrated Security=True";
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(strCn))
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT User_id ,imgUrlOnDisk FROM login", cn))
                {
                    using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            if (dr.Read())
                            {
                                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Convert.ToString(dr["imgUrlOnDisk"]));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    cn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

---

Best way that I suggest you to use ADO.net query is this:

```
try
{
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection))
     {
          try
          {
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType;
               foreach (var p in InParameters)
               {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
               }
               cmd.Connection.Open();
               affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               if (affectedRows == 0)
               {
                    //Zero Record Success
               }
               else
               {
                   if (affectedRows > 1)
                   {
                        //Many Record Success
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        //One Record Success
                   }
               }
           }
           catch (Exception InnerEx)
           {
                //Handle your error
           }
           finally
           {
               if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
               {
                   cmd.Connection.Close();
               }
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: A `using` statement would be more succinct. Also your also uses other objects that implement `IDisposable` which are not being disposed of correctly.

Comment: @Dai About other objects use, you are right but abouy using it's not different with my code

Comment: Can you tell me the data of your table, So I can test it for you

Comment: @ImranShams create table login
(
 User_id CHAR(7),
 user_name VARCHAR(15),
 password VARCHAR(20),
 img IMAGE
)

Comment: I need an example of  img column, Also you are in another mistake, Never try to store files and images in database

Comment: @ImranShams yes I did

Comment: Why are you use byte array to store Image? This is a bad way body

Comment: I'm here to help you, Please let me know if you have any issue or problem

Comment: AS I have mention in the question I got this code from the microsoft site. I m a totally newbie to the programming.So I used that code as it is. @ImranShams

Comment: So I suggest you to store image on disk and then store image URL in database. change your column type to nvarchar(max) and store data and use my code to solve your problem.

Comment: Dear @Pegasus if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thank you @Pegasus, If any time you need help just mention me and I will help you as soon as possible